# Failed to trigger translation for DWF files to STEP

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I’m trying to translate my .DWF file to STEP using the [Model Derivative API](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job):

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn":"<<DWF URN HERE>>"
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
        {
            "type": "step"
        }]
    }
}
```

But the request fails with this reply:

```
{
  "diagnostic": "Failed to trigger translation for this file."
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP export format is currently not available for DWF files :(

Here you can find a list of all the design file formats and the export file format supported for them:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/

You can also access this information programmatically from here:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/formats-GET/

Cheers,

Adam